# How to make a function when pressing a button in KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin

I created a function called "talk" so I want to press a button to execute "talk". I put this to do in the activity_main.xml and everything works fine. The problem comes when I don't want to do it by activity_main but by code in Mainactivity.kt. After the "talk" function is executed I want to make a condition. and I don't know how to do both when pressing the button.

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener{
talk()
if (textView3.text=="hello") {
textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
} else {

}
}
```

this is the code of the function ""talk"" :

```
fun talk(v: View) {
        val intentActionRecognizeSpeech = Intent(
                RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        // Configura el Lenguaje (Español-México)
        intentActionRecognizeSpeech.putExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "es-MX")
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intentActionRecognizeSpeech,
                    RECOGNIZE_SPEECH_ACTIVITY)
        } catch (a: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                    "Tú dispositivo no soporta el reconocimiento por voz",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not understandable. please add clearer explanation and also a desired output maybe along with the result you get now which is not acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, maybe is my english. But check this, I have an app it allow you press a button then you can talk something an the app will write it on a textview. The thing I want to do is, if people say the word "hello" then textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE.

Comment: This could cause you problems, because the `TextView.text` returns an Editable, not a String: `textView3.text=="hello"` Replace it with `textView3.text.toString() == "hello"`. Other than that, I don't understand what you're asking from your description.

Comment: Ok thanks, the thing that I want is how can I use the funtion "talk" in the setOnClickListener event.

Comment: You already are, except you should remove the View parameter from the `talk` function. And remove the `onClick` line from your XML.

Comment: oh thanks a lot now the error is gone.

But now the condition does not works. I mean when textView3.text.toString() == "hello" it does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of initialization give visibility of `textview` then `onclick` give visibility to visible.

Comment: Textview should be visible only if the user say "hello"

Comment: So you can put a condition where if the text is "hello: then give visibility to visible.  Example `if(inputtext.equal("hello")` then give visibility to visible

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to do something like this. Make sure you are using activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha02 or higher

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val talk = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        val text = it.data?.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)?.get(0)
        if (text != null && it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            textView3.text = text
            if (text == "hello") textView.isVisible = true
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
                .putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "es-MX")
            talk.launch(intent)
        }
    }

}
```